# Installing USB Wi-Fi driver on Zorin

Tags: software-installation, wifi, drivers, zorin

I installed Zorin 10 (after trying Mint and Ubuntu).

My problem is I have a TP LINK Archer T2UH USB Wi-Fi adapter. Their website has the Linux driver for it(http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909.zip), but I have no idea how to install it: it has a PDF file explaining the installation process, but I don't have a Ph.D in Linux. Even though it is in English, I have no clue what it is saying.

I have tried multiple ways to get it to work:

- terminal commands from YouTube videos,
- windows wireless drivers,
- etc...

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux!  **;-)** Could you provide a link to the PDF documentation you have tried using?  Please [edit] your question to provide this info. Also review the [editing help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Sorry about that.Thanks for the suggestions.BTW what does readability mean? I looked it up but couldn't find a definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability